# Fade in div with same class name as the same name as my button id

Tags: jquery, button

I have a few buttons that share the same class name as the divs ids that I would like to fade in.

Example:

```
 <div class="one">button</div>

 <div id="one">I am the one div that needs to fade in</div>


 <div class="two">button</div>

 <div id="two">I am the two div that needs to fade in</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a common class/tag for the buttons, and a data-* attribute for the target ID, and retrieve it in your click handler:

HTML:

```
 <div class="button" data-target="one">button</div>

 <div id="one">I am the one div that needs to fade in</div>


 <div class="button" data-target="two">button</div>

 <div id="two">I am the two div that needs to fade in</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).on('click', '.button', function() {
  var id = $(this).data('target');
  $('#' + id).fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: Why appending `#`; store the selector itself in the target. you get more flexibility. target can be class, id, a chained selector or anything.